# How to set property value from SelectList in controller

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I am trying to set a value of a property, which is located in model of my project.
What I want is to select a value in a dropdown list and when i hit create, it sets the selected value to the value of the property, this will obviously take place in the "create" action of the respective controller. The problem is that I am unable to use ".SelectedValue" with the selectlist and set it as the property of the model.

There are two "create" action methods, one parameterized, the other un-parameterized.The former one saves the data to the table and the latter one gets the values. I created an integer list in unparameterized method and tried to put it in ViewBag (which works fine). When I run the code, the view works and the dropdown list is populated by the list items. But after I have entered the necessary details, I hit enter and despite I have set the property of the model to the SelectedValue of the dropdown list, It stays NULL.

**MODEL:**

```
namespace Test.Models
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
public partial class LabAsign
{
    [Display(Name = "ID")]
    public int LbAs_id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Organization ID")]
    public Nullable<int> LbAs_orgId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Labor ID")]
    public Nullable<int> LbAs_LabId { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
    public static int LabId
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.LbAs_CmplntId = new SelectList(db.Complaints, "Cmplnt_Id");  



        var list = new List<int>();
        foreach (var item in db.Labors)
        {
            string c = item.Lab_OrgId.ToString();

            if (c == HomeController.c_orgid.ToString())
            {
                list.Add(item.Lab_id);
            }
        }            
        var selectList = new SelectList(list);
        Session["labid"] = list;
        ViewBag.LbAsLabId = selectList;

        //ViewBag.LbAs_LabId = new SelectList(db.Labors, "Lab_id", 
    "Lab_name");
        ViewBag.LbAs_orgId = new SelectList(db.Organizations, "org_id", 
    "org_name");
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = 
"LbAs_id,LbAs_orgId,LbAs_LabId,LbAs_date,LbAs_CmplntId,LbAs_complStatus")] 
LabAsign labAsign)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var selectList = new 
SelectList((System.Collections.IEnumerable)Session["labid"]);
            LabId = (int)selectList.SelectedValue;
            labAsign.LbAs_LabId = LabId;
            db.LabAsigns.Add(labAsign);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("IndexLbAsOrg");
        }

        ViewBag.LbAs_CmplntId = new SelectList(db.Complaints, 
"Cmplnt_Id","complnt_content", labAsign.LbAs_CmplntId);
        ViewBag.LbAs_LabId = new SelectList(db.Labors, "Lab_id", 
"Lab_name", labAsign.LbAs_LabId);
        ViewBag.LbAs_orgId = new SelectList(db.Organizations, "org_id", 
"org_name", labAsign.LbAs_orgId);
        return View(labAsign);
    }
```

**VIEW :**

```
    @model Test.Models.LabAsign

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Create";
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }

    <h2>Create</h2>


    @using (Html.BeginForm()) 
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <h4>LabAsign</h4>
            <hr />
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" 
})

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LbAs_orgId, "Organization 
ID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2"@*, @style = 
"display:none;"*@ })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LbAs_orgId, new { 
htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control"@*, @style = 
"display:none;"*@, 
@Value = Session["UserId"]} })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LbAs_orgId, 
"", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LbAs_LabId, "LbAs_LabId", 
htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownList("LbAsLabId", null, htmlAttributes: 
new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LbAs_LabId, 
"", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
```

As you can see, I am using Sessions to transport the list from one create method to the other, declare a new selectlist and use SelectedValue from the selectlist to update the property but this throws this exception:

```
    System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance 
    of an object.
```

When I try to directly set the value of the dropdown list by setting the value of the view as:

```
    @Html.DropDownList("LbAsLabId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = 
    "form-control", @Value = Session["labid"] })
```

the property value is set to NULL but no exceptions are thrown

Comment: In which line the exception thrown? Probably you should have null checking before passing populated `SelectList` to view. Also avoid using `ViewBag` property name with same viewmodel property name bound to `DropDownList`.

Comment: Actually I got it running with view data property